Can't build a C# Native AOT Lambda using sam build on Windows
I am trying to get familiar with building and deploying Native AOT C# Lambdas in order to improve our cold starts and to see if we get any additional benefits. I created a hello world project using the sam init template for C#, .NET 8, and Native AOT. When I run sam build on Windows 11, I get the following error. Appreciate any help here. I can't seem to find a solution.
Executing publish command
Starting container for native AOT build using build image: public.ecr.aws/sam/build-dotnet8:latest-x86_64.
... invoking 'docker run --name tempLambdaBuildContainer-27d26a30-23bd-41a8-b8d7-4c1748e40d0d --rm --volume "C:\dev\Playground\HelloWorldAot":/tmp/source/ -i public.ecr.aws/sam/build-dotnet8:latest-x86_64 dotnet publish
"/tmp/source/src/HelloWorldAot" --output "/tmp/source/src/HelloWorldAot\bin\Release\net8.0\publish" --configuration "Release" --framework "net8.0" --runtime linux-x64 /p:GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles=true --self-contained True
/p:StripSymbols=true' from directory C:\dev\Playground\HelloWorldAot
... docker run:   Determining projects to restore...
... docker run: /tmp/source/src/HelloWorldAot/HelloWorldAot.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
... docker run:   Failed to restore /tmp/source/src/HelloWorldAot/HelloWorldAot.csproj (in 5.79 sec).
ERROR: Container build returned 1


Update: Looks like this may be a problem with my work issued computer. I tried it on my personal computer and it worked as expected. Leaving this open on the chance anyone has any ideas.

#1 Are you behind a proxy? #2 Try in another machine and share the results #3 Do you have installed: dotnet and nuget ? Just to try if your connectivity to nuget is ok, in the same machine install some  nuget package like dotnet tool install --global dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool --version 5.3.9 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/59375752/3957754   Share the results

No proxy. As I mentioned, I tried it on my personal Windows computer and it worked fine. I also tried it on my Mac and had no issues. I do all sorts of .NET development on this computer and have no issues with NuGet other that this one that is specific to .NET Native AOT builds using SAM.
